# How to return collection of ListViewItems?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Sorry for the newbie question about `ListViewItems` but had never used `ListView` before and what I am trying to do is to return all `ListViewItems` from `AnimalManager` class back to UI `lsbOverview` control. Reason to this approach is that I have a `Manager` class which handles all the data and returns it to UI controls. The question is how do I return all items back to `lsboverView` `ListView`?

```
    // declared in AnimalManager class
    private static List<Animal> AnimalList { get; set; }


     public static ListViewItem DisplayAllAnimals()
    {
        //Show animals on ListView by proper column
        foreach (var animal in AnimalList)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(animal.Id); // generated ID
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.AnimalSort); // AnimalSort
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Name); //Name
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Age); //Age
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Gender.ToString()); // Animal gender

            return item;
        }

        // how to return all items back to UI ?
    }


    // Mainform UI class where its used
    lsbOverview.Items.Add(AnimalManager.DisplayAllAnimals());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
// declared in AnimalManager class
    private static List<Animal> AnimalList { get; set; }


     public static ListViewItem[] DisplayAllAnimals()
    {
        //Show animals on ListView by proper column
        var listViewItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
        foreach (var animal in AnimalList)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(animal.Id); // generated ID
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.AnimalSort); // AnimalSort
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Name); //Name
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Age); //Age
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Gender.ToString()); // Animal gender
            listViewItems.Add(item);

        }

        return listViewItems.ToArray();
    }


    // Mainform UI class where its used
    lsbOverview.Items.AddRange(AnimalManager.DisplayAllAnimals());
```

Comment: +1 This works fine! We end up having the same answer. I will change mine a bit to show a slightly different return strategy.

Comment: Correctomundo ! Thanx just what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
    // declared in AnimalManager class
    private static List<Animal> AnimalList { get; set; }


     public static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> DisplayAllAnimals()
    {
        //Show animals on ListView by proper column
        foreach (var animal in AnimalList)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(animal.Id); // generated ID
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.AnimalSort); // AnimalSort
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Name); //Name
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Age); //Age
            item.SubItems.Add(animal.Gender.ToString()); // Animal gender

            yield return item;
        }
    }


    // Mainform UI class where its used
    lsbOverview.Items.AddRange(AnimalManager.DisplayAllAnimals().ToArray());
```

Edit: 
Note the AddRange call instead of Add.
For more information about IEnumerable<> and yield i would suggest google or searching here for a deeper understanding.

Comment: I am sorry, this will not work for the same reasons as @AppDeveloper.

Comment: Oups, damn old controls... Changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think building an array of animals, then using AddRange on the listview could do the trick:

```
public static List<ListViewItem> DisplayAllAnimals()
{
    var animals = new List<ListViewItem>();

    //Show animals on ListView by proper column
    foreach (var animal in AnimalList)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(animal.Id); // generated ID
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.AnimalSort); // AnimalSort
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Name); //Name
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Age); //Age
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Gender.ToString()); // Animal gender

        animals.Add(item);
    }

    return animals;
}


lsbOverview.Items.AddRange(AnimalManager.DisplayAllAnimals().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield return` to return a `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`

```
public static IEnumerable< ListViewItem> DisplayAllAnimals()
{
    //Show animals on ListView by proper column
    foreach (var animal in AnimalList)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(animal.Id); // generated ID
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.AnimalSort); // AnimalSort
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Name); //Name
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Age); //Age
        item.SubItems.Add(animal.Gender.ToString()); // Animal gender

        yield return item;
    }


}
```

You can use this as :

```
lsbOverview.Items.AddRange(AnimalManager.DisplayAllAnimals().ToArray());
```

Comment: I am sorry, AddRange needs a array of ListViewItem. The IEnumerable<> will not work.